# Print all result in loop together

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I am loosing sleep over this. 
SO helps a lot, but still something wrong.

```
def function_input():
    .................... 
    find_input.clear() 
    find_input.send_keys(i)
    button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    f_copy()

def f_copy():
    element3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(" ")

    l=[]
    for element4 in element3:
        element4_list = element4.text

        l.append(pd.DataFrame(element4_list, columns=['a','b','c']))
        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
        df = pd.concat(l).reset_index(drop=True)
        df['Input value'] = i

    print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))    

def loop_page():
    find_next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(" ")    
    if 'no-next-page'in find_next_button.get_attribute(''):
        pass
    elif 'yes-next-page' in find_next_button.get_attribute(''):
        find_next_button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        f_copy()
    else:
        pass

for j in range(1, 5, 1):
    i = j

    f_copy()
    loop_page()
```

The result I get is

```
>>>

+---+----+----+----+        #page 1 (input 1)
|   | a  | b  | c  |
+---|----+----+----+
| 0 | 3  | 1  | 21 |
+---+----+----+----+

+---+----+----+----+        #page 2 (input 1)
|   | a  | b  | c  |       
+---|----+----+----+
| 0 | 5  | 8  | 41 |
+---+----+----+----+

+---+----+----+----+        #page 1 (input 2)
|   | a  | b  | c  |       
+---|----+----+----+
| 0 | 3  | 3  | 3  |
+---+----+----+----+
>>>
```

I tried `df.concat`, but table is not 'seperated'.
I tried every possible loop, still fails.
That was my best loop result.

What the result should be is, to return all result from each page from each input into one table.

```
>>>

+---+----+----+----+        
|   | a  | b  | c  |
+---|----+----+----+
| 0 | 3  | 1  | 21 |
+---+----+----+----+
| 0 | 5  | 8  | 41 |
+---+----+----+----+
| 0 | 3  | 3  | 3  |
+---+----+----+----+
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `pd.concat()` with the dataframe that you want to append along with the new dataframe. Change your code to -

```
def f_copy():
    element3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(" ")

    l=[]
    for element4 in element3:
        element4_list = element4.text

        l.append(pd.DataFrame(element4_list_2, columns=['a','b','c']))
        l['Input value'] = i
        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
        df = pd.concat([df,l]).reset_index(drop=True)

    print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Also, please make sure you are declaring/initializing `df` dataframe outside the loop but inside the scope of the function, that should do it.